# DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www.example.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain

Tags: lets-encrypt

I'm trying to get an SSL certificate using the certbot from letsencrypt, but it keeps saying it's failing at the verification stage, with this error 'DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) - check that a DNS record exists for this domain'

I currently have one host record, which is an A record, host '@' and value is set to my public ip address. Am I supposed to have more host records on my namecheap account?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a dns record similar to this:

```
www 3600 in CNAME @
```

or you can just copy the A record:

```
www 3600 in A 46.101.145.73
```

The first option is more resilient (it will carry all dns records from @ to www, and this can have unintended consequences), the second is more performant.

Comment: What is the structure of the answer here? `name, timeout, type, data`?

Comment: Yes, the structure is
Name: www
Timeout/TTL: 3600 seconds (1 hour)
Type: IN
Data Type: A (IPv4 address)
Data: 46.101.145.73 (IPv4 address)